# How to get system image list icon index of an IShellItem?

Tags: windows, shell, winapi, com

Given a Windows Vista or newer **`IShellItem`**, how do i get the system image list icon index associated with that item?

For example *(pseudo-code)*:

```
IShellItem networkFolder = SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_NetworkFolder, 0, 0, IShellItem);
Int32 iconIndex = GetSmallSysIconIndex(networkFolder);


Int32 GetSmallSysIconIndex(IShellItem item)
{
   //TODO: Ask Stackoverflow
}
```

### Background

In the olden days (Windows 95 and newer), we could ask the shell to give us the system imagelist index for an item's icon. We did it using [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  The SHGet­File­Info function [gets the icon by asking the shell namespace for the icon index in the system imagelist](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110127-00/?p=11653):

```
HICON GetIconIndex(PCTSTR pszFile)
{
    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    HIMAGELIST himl = SHGetFileInfo(pszFile, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX));
    if (himl) {
       return sfi.iIcon;
    } else {
       return -1;
    }
}
```

That works when you are using an item in the shell namespace that corresponds to a file. But the shell supports things besides files and folders in the filesystem.

**Icon Index from IShellFolder**

The general solution for getting information about an object in the shell namespace comes from using the way you represent an *item* in the shell namespace:

- **`IShellFolder`**: the folder that the *thing* sits in, along with
- **child `PIDL`**: the id of the *thing* in that folder

From that there are [ways to get the system image list index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353059/how-to-get-the-shell-image-index-of-an-object-in-the-shell-namespace):

```
Int32 GetIconIndex(IShellFolder folder, PITEMID_CHILD childPidl)
{
   //Note: I actually have no idea how to do this.
}
```

**But IShellFolder is out; we're using IShellItem now**

Starting with Windows Vista, `IShellItem` became [the preferred AP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx)I for navigating the shell. The Windows 95 era API of having to keep an `IShellFolder`+`pidl` pair around [was cumbersome, and error prone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110831-00/?p=9763/).

The question becomes: How to do stuff with it? In particular, how do i get the image index in the system image list of the item? Looking at its methods, there isn't even a way to get its absolute pidl:

- **BindToHandler**: Binds to a handler for an item as specified by the handler ID value (BHID).
- **Compare**: Compares two IShellItem objects.
- **GetAttributes**: Gets a requested set of attributes of the IShellItem object.
- **GetDisplayName**: Gets the display name of the IShellItem object.
- **GetParent**: Gets the parent of an IShellItem object.

I was hoping that the [**Windows Property System**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx), accessible through [`IShellItem2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761130(v=vs.85).aspx), would have a property associated with the shell imagelist icon index. Unfortunately, i don't see any:

- [System.DescriptionID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760159(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.InfoTipText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391574(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.InternalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892886(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.Link.TargetSFGAOFlagsStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760160(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.Link.TargetUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760161(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.NamespaceCLSID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391575(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.Shell.SFGAOFlagsStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760162(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Ways of extracting icons**

There [are many standard ways](https://xkcd.com/927/) of getting the picture that goes with a *thing* in the Windows Shell Namespace:

- [`IExtractIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761854(v=vs.85).aspx). Returns an `HICON`. Requires `IShellFolder`+pidl. If it fails [you can use SHDefExtractIcon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140501-00/?p=1103)
- [`SHDefExtractIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762149(v=vs.85).aspx). Returns an `HICON`. Requires full path to icon file
- [`IThumbnailCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774628(v=vs.85).aspx). Requires `IShellItem`. Returns thumbnail, not icon
- [`IShellImageFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761084(v=vs.85).aspx). Gets a bitmap that represents an `IShellItem`
- [`IThumbnailProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Windows Vista replacement for `IExtractImage`
- [`IExtractImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761848(v=vs.85).aspx). Requires `IShellFolder`+`pidl`.
- [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx). Requires full file path, or an absolute pidl

None of them:

- take an IShellItem
- return an index

Comment: Decompose the IShellItem into an IShellFolder and pidl by using IParentAndItem. Then use IShellIcon::GetIconOf.

Comment: @RaymondChen When the ShellFolder is the zip shell extension, calling `QueryInterface(IID_ShellIcon)` on the `IShellFolder` fails with `E_NOINTERFACE`. Meanwhile, using `SHGetFileInfo` with the absolute pidl returned by `SHGetIDListFromObject` does manage to return an icon index. Is going directly to `IShellIcon` bad form, and it is best to rely on `SHGetFileInfo` to do all the heavy lifting of all these edge cases?

Comment: SHGetFileInfo uses IExtractIcon, which is less efficient than IShellIcon (but then again, if IShellIcon isn't available, you have no choice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it doesn't seem that there's any easy method for this. It simply hasn't been provided in the API.

In your question you say *"But the shell supports things besides files and folders in the filesystem."*, which makes me think you have overlooked that  `SHGetFileInfo` does actually support using PIDLs directly (with the `SHGFI_PIDL` flag) - so it **can** be used on non-filesystem objects. If you still have the full PIDL this is the easiest way to get an icon index, otherwise something like this should hopefully work:

```
int GetIShellItemSysIconIndex(IShellItem* psi)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
    int iIndex = -1;

    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetIDListFromObject(psi, &pidl)))
    {
        SHFILEINFO sfi{};
        if (SHGetFileInfo(reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(pidl), 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX))
            iIndex = sfi.iIcon;
        CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
    }
    return iIndex;
}
```

<strike>Or using Raymond Chen's suggestion:</strike>

```
int GetIconIndex(IShellItem item)
{
    Int32 imageIndex;

    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE parent;
    IShellFolder folder;
    PITEMID_CHILD child;

    //Use IParentAndItem to have the ShellItem 
    //cough up the IShellObject and child pidl it is wrapping.
    (item as IParentAndItem).GetParentAndItem(out parent, out folder, out child);
    try
    {        
       //Now use IShellIcon to get the icon index from the folder and child
       (folder as IShellIcon).GetIconOf(child, GIL_FORSHELL, out imageIndex);
    }
    finally
    {
       CoTaskMemFree(parent);
       CoTaskMemFree(child);
    }

    return imageIndex;
}
```

Turns out that `IShellFolder` doesn't support the `IShellIcon` sometimes. For example attempting to browse inside a zip file. When that happens, the `QueryInterface` of `IShellFolder` for `IShellIcon` fails.

```
shellFolder.QueryInterface(IID_IShellIcon, out shellIcon); //<--fails with E_NOINTERFACE
```

Yet `SHGetFileInfo` knows how to handle it.

So best to not try to get an `IShellIcon` interface yourself. Leave the heavy lifting to `SHGetFileInfo` (at least until someone from Microsoft documents how to use `IShellIcon`).

Answer (score 2):

In your great investigation you forget about IShellIcon interface. It available even in Windows XP.

```
function GetIconIndex(AFolder: IShellFolder; AChild: PItemIDList): Integer; overload;
var
  ShellIcon: IShellIcon;
  R: HRESULT;
begin
  OleCheck(AFolder.QueryInterface(IShellIcon, ShellIcon));
  try
    R := ShellIcon.GetIconOf(AChild, 0, Result);
    case R of
      S_OK:;
      S_FALSE:
        Result := -1; // icon can not be obtained for this object
    else
      OleCheck(R);
    end;
  finally
    ShellIcon := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm going to give it to Jonathan, because he had the missing piece i needed: `SHGetIDListFromObject`. But it looks like your going directly to `IShellIcon` is the slightly better way once i *do* have the `IShellFolder` and child `PIDL`. And you also gave the correct and functioning sample usage of `IShellIcon`.